# excelworkbook.saveas() throwing an error in c#

Tags: c#, excel, save-as

i have saw similar issues addressed in other questions but none helped me solve my particular issue although the exception is the same in all of the questions
this is the exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
> HResult=0x800A03EC
> Message=The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
>
> • Make sure the specified folder exists.
> • Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
> • Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *
> • Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.}

this is my code if you could point out my mistake and possibly the solution that would be much of a life saver.

```
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                return;
            }


            

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1][1] = "total to pay";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2][1] = "due before";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1][lastUsedRow + 1] = richbox[11 + classnumber ].Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2][lastUsedRow + 1] = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.Day) + "-" +Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1))+"-" +Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.Year);

            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coach ceazar\clients holds\test.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: first question: try saving it to a very simple place, such as C:\Users\test.xls and see if you get the same error.  Sometimes spaces in directories can do weird things.

Comment: .. you haven't already got the file open, have you? Are any orphaned Excel tasks running?

Comment: i did try to save on just the desktop, same error appeared

Comment: and no i am making sure that this excel file is not open through task manager

Comment: any other ideas i have really dug deep in trying to solve this issue nothing is working

Comment: and note that i used the same method somewhere else in the program and it worked like a charm but the problem always occured for this specific one